# cv::VideoCapture: accessing the same webcam from two threads

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

I have two classes with two threads: One displays the webcam frames in my GUI, One records a video from the same webcam. 
I'm using a different `cv::VideoCapture` in each class to access my webcam. Both consturctors for my MainWindow and Recorder class have the line `theWebcam.open(INDEX)` to open the webcam. My problem is that about 50% of the time my program crashes on start when it tries to open the second `cv::VideoCapture` object. How can I use the same webcam in both classes?

Answer (score 1):

I have had success with the technique Robert was describing as well. I use pointers to pass images around to different threads and let the main thread create all the VideoCapture objects I need and the namedWindow objects as well. I am now speaking outside of my area of expertise, but my experience suggests that VideoCapture and namedWindow objects from OpenCV can not be created in any thread aside from the main thread, and must instead be passes into secondary threads.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible (but never tried by myself). I prefer following approach:

One thread "communicates" with the camera, i.e. grabs images, and sends one copy to a thread to write to a file and one copy to the gui to show a live image.

Moreover, as long as a camera wouldn't support multicasting (assuming it's an ip-camera) the framerate will most likely drop.

Comment: I'm using a USB webcam. I don't get why it wouldn't be possible. If I comment the Detector out and let just the MainWindow in that displays the video feed from the webcam, I can run 10 instances of the program and they will all display the same video from the same webcam with no problems whatsoever. Why wouldn't it be possible to acess the same webcam twice in the same program if it clearly is possible to access a webcam multiple times?

Comment: Depends on how OpenCV takes care of the camera handles. I know of other libraries that internally store a list of handles and just keep one "instance" of each, so when accessing from different threads it leads to problems/access violation/etc. But I think you should consider my suggestion in using only one camera-connection and distribute copies of the images taken...